# Adding an extra row to a PHP array with new values

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array called $items.  My CMS created this array with three products and I just did a var_dump with the results below.

```
array(3) { [0]=> array(11) { ["item_id"]=> string(4) "1320" ["name"]=> string(5) "ITEM_A" ["price"]=> string(6) "$5.00" } 
           [1]=> array(11) { ["item_id"]=> string(4) "1321" ["name"]=> string(5) "ITEM_B" ["price"]=> string(6) "$5.00" } 
           [2]=> array(11) { ["item_id"]=> string(4) "1323" ["name"]=> string(5) "ITEM_D" ["price"]=> string(6) "$5.00" } 
         }
```

Is there a way I can inject another item, "ITEM_C" into this array so that it's now

```
array(3) { [0]=> array(11) { ["item_id"]=> string(4) "1320" ["name"]=> string(5) "ITEM_A" ["price"]=> string(6) "$5.00" } 
           [1]=> array(11) { ["item_id"]=> string(4) "1321" ["name"]=> string(5) "ITEM_B" ["price"]=> string(6) "$5.00" } 
           [2]=> array(11) { ["item_id"]=> string(4) "1323" ["name"]=> string(5) "ITEM_D" ["price"]=> string(6) "$5.00" } 
           [3]=> array(11) { ["item_id"]=> string(4) "1322" ["name"]=> string(5) "ITEM_C" ["price"]=> string(6) "$5.00" } 
         }
```

and then sort it by "name"?  I basically want to always add one new row to this array which will always have different names and then sort it by the name.  When I do the foreach php command I don't want it to be in the order of ITEM_A, ITEM_B, ITEM_D, ITEM_C.  It needs to be ITEM_A, ITEM_B, ITEM_C, ITEM_D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appending to an array in PHP is easy as `$array[]` :

```
 $myArray = array(1,2,3);
 $myArray[] = 4; //now array(1,2,3,4)
```

So to add to your existing array, first create your new array element

```
$element = array("item_id" => 1322, "name" => "ITEM_C", /*etc.*/);
```

Then add it your array

```
$myArray[] = $element;
```

As for sorting, there are [various sort functions](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php) depending on your exact needs. Since you're sorting according to a given array key, you'll probably need to call [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) with a given function.

```
function nameCompare($a, $b)
{
    $a = $a["name"];
    $b = $b["name"];
    return strcmp($a, $b);
}

usort($myArray, 'nameCompare');
```

Comment: $myArray[] = 4; works good but how do I assign it to specific column names like "item_id" and "name"?

Comment: Just create that sub-array first. I've updated my post.